# Changing Azure Web App settings

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Does changing an Azure web app setting changes it in the deployment slot?
For example, If I changed the PHP version on the production slot, would it automatically be changed in the staging slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless you swap the slots and enable "Slot Setting" in the "Application Settings". The changes will not be reflected in the other Slots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. Each deployment slot is like a full App Service instance. The changes are **not reflected to any other slots**.