# Environment-variable as condition for rewrite rule in web.config in azure web app

Tags: .net, azure, web-config, staging, slot

I want to use a different robots.txt for my different environments (such as staging and production). Is there a way to make the environment-variable as condition instead of

```
pattern="somePattern"
```

The variable is set in the app-settings with the key "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT".

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    <!-- Robots Debug-->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite LIVE robots.txt" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="robots.txt" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/robots.prod.txt" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="somePattern" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 50e2110f-47f1-4626-828d-5a9fd313625a-->
```

Comment: why don't you use the Azure app setting variables setting with the slot? See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51637307/7073340

Comment: This is exacly what i am using. I have a slot for production and staging. I want this rule only to effect the production slot.